# Connection refused to localhost with android phone

Tags: android, connection, localhost

My phone must connect to my localhost.
I looked up my ip adress, so the connection string is something like "http://192.168.x.x:9000".
When I go to the adress with my pc, it works fine. When I go to the adress with my phone's browser, the page isn't available.

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: what localhost? localhost on your phone or connected PC? If your PC, then you will need to proxy your internet connection.

Comment: Yes, the localhost on my PC. How do i proxy my internet connection? I'm very new to these things, I'm not sure I understand

Comment: seem my answer below, its pretty simple on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to your phone's settings
2. Go to the network settings
3. Go to WIFI
4. Long tap on your WIFI network

After this, their should be an option to modify the settings.

1. Click Advanced Options
2. Go to Proxy Settings and select manual
3. Enter your PC's IP address in hostname.
4. For port, enter the port of the proxy you are running on your PC
5. Save!

Comment: Thanks, though it gives an error "connection through proxy server failed" in my browser :(

Comment: @LaureDM What program are you using on your PC? It seems likely that either the IP address of your machine or the port entered are incorrect.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio, and in hostname I filled in my Ip address so "192.168.x.x" and in the port field I filled in 9000.

Comment: are you trying to proxy HTTP web traffic to Android Studio? I didn't know this was possible ( I use either Fiddler or Charles myself depending on my PC's OS). If you are using Android Studio, would you mind pointing me to the guide your using, or how you are accessing whichever tool/view you are using in the menu?